Does the Sonic Classic Collection have DS Download play?
There is this DS game of Sonic the Hedgehog that plays Sonic 1, 2, 3, and Sonic and Knuckles. Does it support DS Download Play so I can play with only one game card? If it doesn't support Download Play, does it still support local multiplayer?

Shout out to @pinckerman for the edit.

@pinckerman Did you create a Sonic tag? I didn't see it in the list of Sonic tags earlier.

Hi Alex, yep, I did

Awesome. Thanks for doing that. I just recently figured out people could create tags. Once I looked up [sonic-classic-collection] on this site, and I noticed the edit button and figured out how to write the description for the tag. How did you do it?

No worries! You just type the tag, following the "skewer-case-rule" and then press the spacebar to confirm it. If the tag doesn't exsist, you can create it with 300 rep, which you actually have

Oh fun. If I do need to create a tag, where do I go to do that? I'm not going to create a tag, I'm just asking for future references.

Just edit a question and type it in the tag area below, then save your edit

And it just creates the tag like that? Nice. I know how to write the tag description, so now I learned something new about StackExchange. Thanks Pinckerman. Hopefully someone can answer my question about sonic soon, lol.

Lol I guess you have to try by yourself

I was unable to find any form of multiplayer option in the Sonic Classic Collection for DS. The title screen had options for Games, Illustrations, and Credits. The Games section let you select a game to play with no additional options. You can still play as Sonic & Tails in Sonic 2, but Tails was controlled by a CPU.
 

Well that's sad (In some way). Where did you find them?

@Alex I played the game to get these screenshots.

@Stevousiak Oh! You did a great job taking these photos. So they didn't even include the 2 Player option in Sonic 2?

@Alex I did not find any option for it

@Stevousiak Ok, Thank You.
